# unity - Input.GetAxis gives +One without pressing any button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try make simple player movement but when i select in game unity screen in playMode "vertical" & "horizontal" axis equal '1' but if i select other unity window it became '0'... Can't understand what's here happening... And all this without touching WASD

here's the code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxQ5x.jpg)

And the same time if try to use WASD (in game window) it's overwrite and work... but if pressed up WASD it again became 1 and character return to drift in x,y axis

Comment: "if you select other window it became 0" .. well yes, its not focused the input isnt there any more.